Where can I find Hagrid's hut in Hogwarts Legacy?
I know Hagrid isn't in Hogwarts Legacy, but is his hut (house) maybe in Hogwarts Legacy?

If it is in Hogwarts Legacy, can someone point me to the hut? Where can I find it?

If you exit Hogwarts from the Clock Tower, then you'll find it on the left side when you exit the bridge.

It doesn't look much like Hagrid's Hut from the Harry Potter Movies, but this is technically his hut. It's called the "Groundkeeper's Hut" in Hogwarts Legacy.


